# Virtual Box not compatible with Apple Private Relay

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant

I am running some local development vagrant boxes on macOS Monterey.

I have Apple Private Relay turned on.

Whenever I start the vagrant box, the Apple Private Relay Turns off.

Is there a way to configure Vagrant/virtual box so it is compatible with the Apple Private Relay?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: Ive read through the apple private relay info, done a bunch of google searches, but not really coming up with an answer so far, so I dont really know where else to look for an answer.

Comment: That information needs to be in the question.